# Как я могу передать в тело json post запроса строку, где есть столбец типа enum

Tags: json, postgresql, post, spring-mvc, enum

Потихоньку изучаю. Наткнулся на просторах интернета задачку, где нужно добавить в таблицу столбец с типом данных ENUM. Решил попробовать. У меня в БД PostgreSQL есть таблица, в котором есть столбец с типом данных enum инициализирую его я следующим образом.

```
-- CREATE TYPE statusProjest AS ENUM ('NotStarted','Active','Completed');
CREATE TABLE "project" (
    "id" SERIAL  PRIMARY KEY,
    "name" TEXT DEFAULT '',
    "dateStart" DATE NOT NULL,
    "dateCompletion" DATE NOT NULL,
    "status" statusProjest
);
```

Я создал repository

```
    private static String insertQuery = "INSERT INTO \"project\"(\"name\" , \"dateStart\" , \"dateCompletion\", \"status\") " +
            "VALUES (?,?,?,?) " +
            "RETURNING \"id\", \"name\" , \"dateStart\" , \"dateCompletion\", \"status\" ";

    @Override
    public Project insert(Project entity) {
        Object[] params = new Object[] { entity.getName(), entity.getDateStart(), entity.getDateCompletion(), entity.getStatus()};
        int[] types = new int[] { Types.VARCHAR, Types.DATE, Types.DATE, Types.VARCHAR};
        SqlRowSet rowSet = jdbcOperations.queryForRowSet(insertQuery, params, types);
        if (!rowSet.next()) {
            return null;
        }
        return new Project(
                rowSet.getInt(1),
                rowSet.getString(2),
                rowSet.getDate(3),
                rowSet.getDate(4),
                rowSet.getString(5)
        );
    }
```

И controller

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    ProjectResource post(@RequestBody ProjectResource resource) {
        Project entity = projectRepository.insert(resource.toEntity());
        if (entity == null) return null;
        return new ProjectResource(entity);
    }
```

В entity я столбец status обозначил как String. Но из-за этого у меня происходит конфликт типов данных. Был бы рад за любую помощь. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Ты передаешь в инсерт 5 значений, вместо 4

Comment: @Alexander Pavlov К сожалению проблема не в этом.  И пока не совсем понимаю как это может повлиять на работоспособность, не могли б Вы объяснить этот момент?

Comment: У тебя четыре `?,?,?,?` и в четвёртую позицию ты передаёшь дату `entity.getDateCompletion()`

Comment: К сожалению это опечатка, проблема остаётся та же.

Comment: Если у тебе в `Project` enum, то так тоже нельзя ` rowSet.getString(5)`. А вообще, стоило бы и ошибку и стэктрэйс показать, надоело гадать.